# Insert file into mysql database as varbinary datatype

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, file, varbinary

I have an error when I wanna insert my file into database. I have file_proposal column that has VARBINARY(100) datatype. So i cast my file that saved in $content variable into VARBINARY datatype. But i get an error.

here's my error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARBINARY(100)))' at line 1

this is my query

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO `proposal` (`id_mhs`, `id_status`, `judul_proposal`, `abstraksi_proposal`, `nama_file_proposal`, `file_proposal`) VALUES ('$id_mhs',2,'$judul_proposal', '$abstraksi_proposal', '$file_proposal', (CAST('$content' AS VARBINARY(100)))");
```

and this is my database :
[proposal database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7v1z.png)

Comment: you need to use double quotes, when passing variables like this. with this, you're pretty much passing string to every data type

Comment: Missing a closing bracket!

Comment: Also I've never used `varbinary`, is that the way to insert data? Your column `file_proposal` already is of type `varbinary(100)`, so I wonder if that `(CAST('$content' AS VARBINARY(100)))` is really necessary.

Comment: @kenzotenma still get same error message :(

Comment: @kerbholz the open bracket and close bracket have same count. and i read in some tutorial to insert data that's one of some way to insert data. i'll try in another way :)) thanks

Comment: I count 5 `(` and 4 `)` in that query.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use double quotes

Try this Query :

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO `proposal` (`id_mhs`, `id_status`, `judul_proposal`, `abstraksi_proposal`, `nama_file_proposal`, `file_proposal`) VALUES ('".$id_mhs."','2','".$judul_proposal."', '".$abstraksi_proposal."', '".$file_proposal."', (CAST('".$content."' AS VARBINARY(100)))");
```

Comment: "_Need to use double quotes_" Not really

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem. this is my query :

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO `proposal` (`id_mhs`, `id_status`, `judul_proposal`, `abstraksi_proposal`, `nama_file_proposal`, `file_proposal`) VALUES ('$id_mhs', $id_status, '$judul_proposal', '$abstraksi_proposal', '$file_proposal', CONVERT('$content', BINARY))");
```